# Hide all div has class hidecategory except first div

Tags: jquery

I want to hide all div has class hidecategory except first div

I have used that jQuery code

```
$(".hidecategory").hide();
$('.hidecategory:first').show();
```

But I need same functionalty if i click h1 tag show parent class and hide other div has class hidecategory

Html Code

```
<h1 class="maincategory">Accounting & Financial</h1>
<div class="category-section addspanwarp hidecategory" style="display: block;"></div>
<h1 class="maincategory">Business Consultants</h1>
<div class="category-section addspanwarp hidecategory" style="display: none;"></div>
<h1 class="maincategory">Business Consultants</h1>
<div class="category-section addspanwarp hidecategory" style="display: none;"></div>
<h1 class="maincategory">Business Consultants</h1>
<div class="category-section addspanwarp hidecategory" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Your html structure is wrong.You need to use `ul-li` structure.And Also you need to close the `div` tags that are of class `hidecategory`

Comment: and also you are not closing any of your div tags

Comment: The h2 had no parent. You want to close al exept the nest or prev?

Comment: but your h1 tags doesnt have any parent tag? are you sure the html pasted here is the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$('.maincategory').click(function(){
    $(".hidecategory").hide();
    $(this).next('.hidecategory').show();
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YFUqZ/)

Answer (score 2):

Correct You HTML. Use `ul-li`.

```
<ul>
    <li class="maincategory">Accounting & Financial</li>
    <li class="category-section addspanwarp hidecategory">Accounting & Financial Content</li>
    <li class="maincategory">Business Consultants</li>
    <li class="category-section addspanwarp hidecategory">Business Consultants Content</li>
    <li class="maincategory">Consultants</li>
    <li class="category-section addspanwarp hidecategory">Content</li>
</ul>
```

You can try this

```
$('.hidecategory:not(:first)').hide();
$('.maincategory').click(function () {
    $(".hidecategory").hide();
    $(this).next('.hidecategory').show();
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RY8hs/)

Answer (score 1):

Should do the trick

```
$('h1').click(function(){
    $(".hidecategory").hide();
    $(this).next('.hidecategory').show();
});
```

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZvy4/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `$(".hidecategory").not(':first')` would select the elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".hidecategory").find(":gt(0)").css('display','none');
```